# Matlab: Removing fields from TreeBagger class to save memory

Tags: matlab

I'm training a random forest in Matlab using `Treebagger()` on a quite large dataset. Memory is an issue and I saw that the returned Treebagger class contains data about a lot of things I don't think are necessary to `predict()` another dataset. E.g. the class includes the whole training data (fields X and Y) which uses a lot of memory.

So how do i remove a field from a Treebagger class? Using `rmfield(class,'X')` or `class.X = [];` didn't work.

Or is this a very bad idea to begin with?

Comment: While I do not know how the class works, it kind of seems a bad idea. Its must be there for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X` is a read-only field, which cannot be set or removed. There is a `compact` method associated with `TreeBagger()` which creates a minified version of the original object.

For example,

```
load fisheriris
rng(1); % For reproducibility
Mdl = TreeBagger(50,meas,species,'OOBPrediction','On','Method','classification');

cMdl = Mdl.compact();
```

Comparing the memory of the two objects using, `whos Mdl cMdl`

```
Name      Size             Bytes  Class                Attributes

Mdl       1x1             488373  TreeBagger                     
cMdl      1x1             452586  CompactTreeBagger
```

If you look into the compacted object, `cMdl` you won't find the training data `X` and `Y` in it.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Ty a lot!

Comment: @lmoes glad it helped!